# Is the CardNumberElement from stipe usable?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stipe in my react web app and I need custom fields for card number, cvv and expiry date. I have spent 2 hour searching the internet for single example that uses the CardNumberElement but I cannot find any. So I am staring to doubt if that component can even be used.

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Stripe's [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) for react have examples for both types of available fields. You can check their `sandbox` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-card-detailed-omfb3?file=/src/App.js:342-351) for a start to see the integration. You can customize the styles based on your styles/theme.

Comment: Hey thank you but you see I need to use the component called CardNumberElement. The links you have attached only uses the CardElement component. I have actually solved that by just blindly using those components without knowing anything about them (The docs are not really clear) and after a little trial and error it worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.